# Apply hue/saturation filters to image with OpenGL

Tags: opengl, image-processing

I have an image in OpenGL that I am attempting to apply a simple HSB filter to. The user selects a hue value, I shade the image appropriately, display it, and everyone is happy. The problem I am running into is that the code I have inherited that worked on a previous system (Solaris, presuming OpenGL 2.1) does not work on our current system (RHEL 5, OpenGL 3.0).

Right now, the image appears in grey-scale, no matter what saturation is set to. However, brightness does seem to be acting appropriately. The relevant code has been reproduced below:

```
// imageData - unsigned char[3*width*height]
// (red|green|blue)Channel - unsigned char[width*height]
// brightnessBias - float in range [-1/3,1/3]
// hsMatrix - float[4][4] Described by algorithm from 
//            http://www.graficaobscura.com/matrix/index.html 
//            (see Hue Rotation While Preserving Luminance)

glDrawPixels(width, height, format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData);

// Split into RGB channels
glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, redChannel);
glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_GREEN, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, greenChannel);
glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_BLUE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, blueChannel);

// Redraw and blend RGB channels with scaling and bias
glPixelZoom(1.0, 1.0);
glRasterPos2i(0, height);

glPixelTransferf(GL_RED_BIAS, brightnessBias);
glPixelTransferf(GL_GREEN_BIAS, brightnessBias);
glPixelTransferf(GL_BLUE_BIAS, brightnessBias);

glDisable(GL_BLEND);

glPixelTransferf(GL_RED_SCALE, hsMatrix[0][0]);
glPixelTransferf(GL_GREEN_SCALE, hsMatrix[1][0]);
glPixelTransferf(GL_BLUE_SCALE, hsMatrix[2][0]);
glDrawPixels(width, height, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, redChannel);

glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE);

glPixelTransferf(GL_RED_SCALE, hsMatrix[0][1]);
glPixelTransferf(GL_GREEN_SCALE, hsMatrix[1][1]);
glPixelTransferf(GL_BLUE_SCALE, hsMatrix[2][1]);
glDrawPixels(width, height, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, greenChannel);

glPixelTransferf(GL_RED_SCALE, hsMatrix[0][2]);
glPixelTransferf(GL_GREEN_SCALE, hsMatrix[1][2]);
glPixelTransferf(GL_BLUE_SCALE, hsMatrix[2][2]);
glDrawPixels(width, height, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, blueChannel);

// Reset pixel transfer parameters
glDisable(GL_BLEND);
glPixelTransferf(GL_RED_SCALE, 1.0f);
glPixelTransferf(GL_GREEN_SCALE, 1.0f);
glPixelTransferf(GL_BLUE_SCALE, 1.0f);
glPixelTransferf(GL_RED_BIAS, 0.0f);
glPixelTransferf(GL_GREEN_BIAS, 0.0f);
glPixelTransferf(GL_BLUE_BIAS, 0.0f);
```

The brightness control works as intended, however, when the glPixelTransferf(GL_*_SCALE) calls are left in, the image is displayed in greyscale. Compounding all of this is the fact that I have no prior experience with OpenGL, so I find a lot of links for what I presume are more modern techniques that I simply can't make sense of.

EDIT:

I believe the theory behind what was being done was a hack at doing the matrix multiplication through the draw calls, because GL_LUMINANCE treats the one value as the value for all three components, so if you follow the components through that drawing, you expect

```
// After glDrawPixels(..., redChannel)
new_red = red*hsMatrix[0][0]
new_green = red*hsMatrix[1][0]
new_blue = red*hsMatrix[2][0]
// After glDrawPixels(..., greenChannel)
new_red = red*hsMatrix[0][0] + green*hsMatrix[0][1]
new_green = red*hsMatrix[1][0] + green*hsMatrix[1][1]
new_blue = red*hsMatrix[2][0] + green*hsMatrix[2][1]
// After glDrawPixels(..., blueChannel)
new_red = red*hsMatrix[0][0] + green*hsMatrix[0][1] + blue*hsMatrix[0][2]
new_green = red*hsMatrix[1][0] + green*hsMatrix[1][1] + blue*hsMatrix[1][2]
new_blue = red*hsMatrix[2][0] + green*hsMatrix[2][1] + blue*hsMatrix[2][2]
```

Because it was turning out greyscale anyway and from a similar-ish example, I had thought that I might have needed to do the glPixelTransfer calls before calling glDrawPixels, but that was amazingly slow.

Comment: As additional information, I can verify that the values for the hsMatrix also appear to be correct (e.g. for hue=0, saturation=1, it is the identity matrix and for hue=0, saturation=0, it is three rows of [0.3086, 0.6094, 0.0820]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, what the hell is that ?!

For your question, I'd replace GL_LUMINANCE in your 3 glDrawPixels by GL_RED, GL_GREEN and GL_BLUE respectively.

However :

glPixelTransfer is *bad*

glDrawPixels is *bad*

Is there a single reason why you're not using a super-simple fragment shader to do the conversion ? It's a simple matrix multiplication, and you're under ogl3.0...

- Create a texture from imageData, this needs to be done only once.
- Make a shader that reads the color from the texture, multiply it by the color conversion matrix, and display it
- Bind the computed color matrix
- Draw a fullscreen quad. Even an 5 year old card will get 500 fps out of this.

Comment: Will be giving this a go. I had hoped to be able to get away with minor changes, but this kind of confirmed my suspicions that it wasn't particularly worth it.

Also, I tried replacing GL_LUMINANCE with the respective component enumeration, but the effect that had was to make the image primarily green when fully desaturated. I've updated the OP to include my interpretation of what that code is supposed to do.